# Substituting sine function to cosine function in Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

Suppose that the Bessel function is defined as:
$$
J_{n}(\beta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{j(\beta\,sin\,u-nu)}du
$$
Does the following integral have any relationship to the Bessel function?
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{j(\beta\,cos\,u-nu)}du
$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\exp\Big(j~\big(\beta\,\cos\,u-nu\big)\Big)~du~=~j^n~J_n\big(\beta\big).$$

Comment: How did you arrive at the form $j^n J_n(\beta)?$